# How do I install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation

How can I install SharePoint Server 2010 or any version of SharePoint on Windows 7 (64-bit)?

Are there are sequence of steps to install it? Please let me know the version of the software clearly.

Answer (score 8):

Check below article, It will help you:

**Reference**:

1. [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)
2. More on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+2010+windows+7+installation).

Comment: Thats a best case scenario walkthrough, I followed it to the letter and had problems.